# How to write an equation on the ylabel of a figure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure

I'm trying to write the following math on the ylabel of a figure in MATLAB,

```
\norm{\boldsymbol{\tilde{y}}(t)}_2
```

I've tried this,

```
ylabel('\norm\boldmath{\bf{$y$}}$(t)$', 'interpreter', 'latex');
```

But got the following error,
Warning: Error updating Text.

Character vector must have valid interpreter syntax:
\norm\boldmath{\bf{$y$}}$(t)$

If I use,

```
ylabel('$|\!|\boldmath{\bf{y}}(t)|\!|_2$', 'interpreter', 'latex');
```

I get,

[image]

but I want the 2-norm of this,

[image]

Comment: IIRC MATLAB has only core-LaTeX, and no optional packages. Adding packages yourself to MATLAB is so difficult, that even exporting the figure as-is without `ylabel` and then using Tikz to write labels is easier.

Comment: Your LaTeX code doesn’t match your expected result. Do you know LaTeX? If not, search on https://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CrisLuengo See the new edited question.

Comment: You want the “y” bold and italic? And the “t” upright? That is ... uncommon. Did you try adding `\it` and `\rm`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo No, I want everything italic. The reason that "t" is upright in my image is that I couldn't make it italic. Yes, I tried them but didn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\norm` isn't available, but you can use `|\!\`.

I can't see a way to do (the revised question) in math, but you can do it in text with `\textbf{\emph{y}}`.

```
ylabel('$|\!|\textbf{\emph{y}}(\mathrm{t})|\!|_2$', 'interpreter', 'latex');
```

If you don't really want the `t` to be upright:

```
ylabel('$|\!|\textbf{\emph{y}}(t)|\!|_2$', 'interpreter', 'latex');
```

Comment: @Mohammad: thanks. Let me know if the new answer isn't exactly what you want.